# How to stretch/pull block from bottom up?

Tags: css

Could we fix bottom side and increase the height by increase top side while adding some text to block?

for Example:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.outer > p {
  
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <p>
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <p>
      My text block <br> 
      My text block <br> 
        fghfgh<br>
    </p>
</div>
```

for display: line, block displays text perfectly but for display: absolute not

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements are but this is one possible solution. Use `position: relative;` on the parent element, the element containing the text block you want the text to grow from the bottom up, then use `position: absolute;` on the block with text.

An example.

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
}
.outer > p {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <p>
        My text block;
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: i need to increase height of block https://jsfiddle.net/wwvbvzv4/  bottom side is not increase like in your example i'ts good

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are trying to do but increasing the height based on content at the bottom requires placing the content **at** the bottom.

Here, flexbox can help:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum autem perferendis cum ducimus sint, accusantium!
</div>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores blanditiis esse cumque deserunt optio modi, molestias quaerat officia consequatur adipisci repellendus corrupti ea pariatur similique laborum dolorum ipsum accusamus, sit omnis ullam ipsam
  ipsa?
</div>
```

The parents should be aligned, I assume, so making them `inline-flex` and vertically aligned to the bottom would seem most likely.

Similar results *might* be obtained just using `inline-block` and the same vertical alignment...depending on the actual requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but my block has display: absolute , and here is not work block like display: inline = /  https://jsfiddle.net/wwvbvzv4/1/

Comment: Then you need to edit your code **into the question**.